# SimpleTextLoader UDF in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I want to create a Custom Load function for Pig UDF, I have created a SimpleTextLoader using the link

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html , I have successfully generate the jar file for this code, register in pig and run a Pig Script.I am getting the empty output. I don't know how to solve this issue, any help would be appreciated.

**Below is my Java code**

```
public class SimpleTextLoader extends LoadFunc{
    protected RecordReader in = null;
    private byte fieldDel = '\t';
    private ArrayList<Object> mProtoTuple = null;
    private TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
      public SimpleTextLoader() {
    }

public SimpleTextLoader(String delimiter) 
{
        this();
        if (delimiter.length() == 1) {
            this.fieldDel = (byte)delimiter.charAt(0);
        } else if (delimiter.length() > 1 && delimiter.charAt(0) == '\\') {
            switch (delimiter.charAt(1)) {
            case 't':
                this.fieldDel = (byte)'\t';
                break;

            case 'x':
               fieldDel =
                    Integer.valueOf(delimiter.substring(2), 16).byteValue();
               break;

            case 'u':
                this.fieldDel =
                    Integer.valueOf(delimiter.substring(2)).byteValue();
                break;

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown delimiter " + delimiter);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("PigStorage delimeter must be a single character");
        }
    }

private void readField(byte[] buf, int start, int end) {
        if (mProtoTuple == null) {
            mProtoTuple = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }

        if (start == end) {
            // NULL value
            mProtoTuple.add(null);
        } else {
            mProtoTuple.add(new DataByteArray(buf, start, end));
        }
    }    @Override
    public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {
         try {
            boolean notDone = in.nextKeyValue();
            if (notDone) {
                return null;
            }
            Text value = (Text) in.getCurrentValue();
            System.out.println("printing value"  +value);
            byte[] buf = value.getBytes();
            int len = value.getLength();
            int start = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (buf[i] == fieldDel) {
                    readField(buf, start, i);
                    start = i + 1;
                }
            }
            // pick up the last field
            readField(buf, start, len);

            Tuple t =  mTupleFactory.newTupleNoCopy(mProtoTuple);
            mProtoTuple = null;
            System.out.println(t);
            return t;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            int errCode = 6018;
            String errMsg = "Error while reading input";
            throw new ExecException(errMsg, errCode,
                    PigException.REMOTE_ENVIRONMENT, e);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void setLocation(String string, Job job) throws IOException {
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,string);
    }

    @Override
    public InputFormat getInputFormat() throws IOException {
      return new TextInputFormat();
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareToRead(RecordReader reader, PigSplit ps) throws IOException {
        in=reader;
    }

}
```

**Below is my Pig Script**

```
REGISTER /home/hadoop/netbeans/sampleloader/dist/sampleloader.jar
a= load '/input.txt' using sampleloader.SimpleTextLoader();
store a into 'output';
```

Comment: Are you getting any error logs?

Comment: did not get any error log,job was executed successfully but creating empty file.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `sampleloader.SimpleTextLoader()` that doesn't do anything as it is just an empty constructor.
Instead use `sampleloader.SimpleTextLoader(String delimiter)` which is performing the actual operation of split.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, I have tried with delimiter also ,I am getting empty output,.

Comment: Please refer this link for step by step to load data using pig custom load function [**Here**](http://shrikantbang.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/apache-pig-custom-load-function-2/)